# apt-get install linux-image-extra getting "W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays."

Tags: ubuntu, apt, mdadm, ubuntu-17.04

When installing:

```
sudo apt-get install \
    linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) \
    linux-image-extra-virtual
```

I am getting:

```
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
```

I found that someone else has had a similar issue: [apt-get update mdadm scary warnings](https://serverfault.com/questions/363543/apt-get-update-mdadm-scary-warnings)

So I followed the instructions:

```
/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Then:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

But the output is:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-30-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
```

lsb_release -a

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

vim /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This configuration was auto-generated on Thu, 10 Aug 2017 15:23:15 +0000 by mkconf
```

/etc/fstab

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0
/var/swap.1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

I think this started happening after I added:

```
/var/swap.1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Is there something else I need to do?

I am running a VM with the help of Vagrant.

**UPDATE 1**

I found another similar question to mine": https://askubuntu.com/questions/834903/i-dont-have-a-raid-but-get-the-warning-mdadm-conf-defines-no-arrays

I added:

```
ARRAY <ignore> devices=/dev/sda1
```

I added 1 at the end because I don't have `/dev/sda` stand alone.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            473M     0  473M   0% /dev
tmpfs            97M  3.1M   94M   4% /run
/dev/sda1        19G  4.8G   15G  26% /
tmpfs           483M     0  483M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           483M     0  483M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
vagrant_        384G   48G  337G  13% /vagrant
vagrant_www_    384G   48G  337G  13% /vagrant/www
tmpfs            97M     0   97M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I am doing this right?
What does this do?

The warnings to have gone away.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This warning is normal. Ignore it.

`update-initramfs` needs to figure out what kernel modules will be needed to boot your system. In this case, it's checking whether the RAID modules will be needed, by running `mdadm` to check whether your root filesystem is on a RAID array. Since you don't have any RAID arrays at all, `mdadm` prints a warning -- but this is OK, because `update-initramfs` has found what it needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your update, you should be using `/dev/sda`. `/dev/sda1` refers to a disk partition, while `/dev/sda` refers to the physical disk itself. Try running the `lsblk` tool and judging by the output you posted from `df -h`, you should get something along the lines of:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   19G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0   19G  0 disk /
```

RAID arrays can be split into separate partitions so they are treated as functionally identical to physical devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me, you try to keep warnings-free logs.  I add the following to any script where that `mdadm.conf` warning might lead someone else to think the script is buggy.

```
grep "ARRAY devices" /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf >/dev/null || echo "ARRAY devices=/dev/sda" | sudo -A tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf >/dev/null;
```

It does what you describe having done in your "UPDATE 1", but in a nice easy set it and forget it way.

The first phrase quietly checks the `mdadm.conf` file for any array devices.
The `||` causes the next phrase to be executed, if no arrays devices are defined, or quit immediately if any have been defined.

The middle phrase echoes the setting text.

The `|` pipes the setting text through to the `tee` command.

The `sudo -A` phrase runs `tee` as root, automatically if an ASK_PASS service is running, or pauses for user input otherwise.

The `tee -a` command **appends** the config text to the end of the file and to the console.

The `>/dev/null` lines swallow verbose output.

Answer (score 0):

I had after an debian 9 Update this Error

/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

First I make the Check:
update-initramfs -u

Second I write this in the root shell
grep "ARRAY devices" /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf >/dev/null || echo "ARRAY devices=/dev/sda" | sudo -A tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf >/dev/null;

Third I make the Check again
update-initramfs -u

And there was no error in the shell

Then I checked the mdam.conf
kate /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

Solution

## This configuration was auto-generated on Fri, 30 Mar 2018 13:01:54 +0200 by mkconf

ARRAY devices=/dev/sda